# Which topology textbook has the greatest amount of ancillary support available on the Internet?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, self-learning, education, learning

I'm considering to begin upon the study of topology and am wondering which book would the best option. I've even started reading Munkres and G. F. Simmons, but the problem is neither book has any "Answers" section at the back to enable me to double-check my work against someone else's, especially, for example, when I'm required to find out whether two sets are equal or which one is properly contained in the other.

So which textbook on topology has got the most amount of ancilliary support---in the form of solutions to exercises, videos, or lecture notes---available on the internet?

I know that the MIT OCW features a course based on Munkres. What else? What other institution offer similar support material on this book?

Answer (score 1):

This may not answer your question, but here's the solution to Munkres's text.

http://dbfin.com/topology/munkres/